# Compositeness tests for numbers of the form $k \cdot b^n \pm c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

Can you provide proofs or counterexamples for the following claims?

*Claim 1*

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . 
>   Let $M= k \cdot b^{n}-c $ where $k,b,n,c$ are natural numbers such that $ k>0$ , $ b>1$ , $ n>1$ and $ c>0$. Let $a$ be a natural number greater than two such that $\left(\frac{a-2}{M}\right)=-1$ and $ \left(\frac{a+2}{M}\right)=1$ where $ \left(\frac{}{}\right)$ denotes Jacobi symbol. Let $ S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $ S_0$ equal to the modular $P_{kb}(a)\phantom{5} \text{mod} \phantom{5} M$. Then, if $ M$ is prime  then $ S_{n-1} \equiv P_{c-1}(a) \pmod{M}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJytVE1z2yAQvedXEB0iiJAbKbfIzHSm01t96y0fHsAri5EMGkCxW0_-e7Gk8Ufigw7ltG_f7tuFBdbtDN55gyMPzuOaCqqpJGy_YPW9eNOpLDh7LLaVagDf4toaDbIGi3ma0wVhLM3Q3R068yeDPyOUJwkpHFuYFc7vW9PICsQfV8E7DtI0o_xbTkJsIb1l2Vgi2HOm04xezTtkuVNWEqoUqsSOsU-BWKahgbGEBd9Zjb3t4AhK3jgg5CMiNyso0Y8qdH_c_dMNCkuVqJ6zhwEc1pj6i3vY_dy1FkcvL8H0-xptOueRALS2EFiLfMU1-gvW3IYKpFeAJgiKeT5BT1zXC0f8SU5PktNT5eQ8myAnp-3WwUkraK_bWdlp6ZXRS8mb8cJF9Hk89Fcyc3wNOFydw6BOuVd7cd7imiShJbkyPkoOWAT8Nph7_RFAOgDZx_WtI-VQa9XmbONfm_3fBaXZtMYpPxb9rnQ4My59f_GWuGZKt51fCrPDGY1r9BTTrVr5iuUPhIozNqexuGT1GftIY33JyktlecnyfhbMQQPSG4uf4_4RxK9UdN4b7djvMAfacAENi2MyvoohDTHU_xoDIqinXGW2o-f4lMg_aehZAg==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) .

*Claim 2*

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . 
>   Let $N= k \cdot b^{n}+c $ where $k,b,n,c$ are natural numbers such that $k>0$ , $ b>1$ , $ n>1$ and $ c>0$ . Let $ a$ be a natural number greater than two such that $ \left(\frac{a-2}{N}\right)=1$ and $ \left(\frac{a+2}{N}\right)=1$ where $ \left(\frac{}{}\right)$ denotes Jacobi symbol. Let $ S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $ S_0$ equal to the modular $ P_{kb}(a)\phantom{5} \text{mod} \phantom{5} N$. Then, if $ N$ is prime  then $ S_{n-1} \equiv P_{c-1}(a) \pmod{N}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJytVE1v4yAQvfdXUB9qqEm29u6pDlKlqrduT731IwIyjpEdsAA32Y3630tsKx_dHHxYTvPmzbwZGGDZTOGD1zjy4DyuqKCaSsK2T6y6Fu86kTlnP_N1qWrAl7iyRoOswGI-yegTYSxFV1foyJ0MbkJ5kpDcsd9mgbPrxtSyBPHHlfCBgzJNKf-RkRCbS29ZOlQI9ozpSUrP5u2y3CErCVVyVWDH2LdALCehgaGEBd9ajb1tYQ8KXjsg5DMiFwso0H0Zut9v_vYChaUKVM3YTQ92a0h95B42D5vG4uj1NZh-W6FV6zwSgJYWAmuRL7lGf8Gay1CBdApQB0Exy0boifN64Yi_yelRcnqsnJylI-TkuN06OGgF7WUzLVotvTJ6Lnk93LeIvgyH_kamji8Bh6uzG9Qh92wvzltckSS0JBfGR8kOi4Dfe3OrPwNIeiC7uK51pBxqrFodbfzfZv93QWlWjXHKD0XvlA5nxqXvLt4cV0zppvVzYTY4pXGFbmO6VgtfsuyGUHHEZjQWp6w-Yn_RWJ-y8lRZnrK8mwVzUIP0xuKXuHsE8RsVrfdGO_Yc5kBrLqBmcUyGV9GnIYa6T6NHBHWUK8168OyfEvkCosVY1Q==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) .

I have tested these claims for many random values of $k$ , $b$ , $n$ and $c$ and there were no counterexamples .

Comment: Again, after DavidSpeyer's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1237935/276986) 3 years ago, did you work on the order of $6-2\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Z}/P\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]^\times$ with $P = 2^p-1$ which is the core of the proof of the LLT for the Mersenne numbers ? If so then what finite ring and which elements are you looking at ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two claims are true.

*Proof for Claim 1* :

Let us prove by induction that 
$$S_i\equiv 2^{-kb^{i+1}}(s^{kb^{i+1}}+t^{kb^{i+1}})\pmod M\tag1$$
where $s:=a-\sqrt{a^2-4},t=a+\sqrt{a^2-4}$.

$(1)$ holds for $i=0$ since
$$S_0\equiv P_{kb}(a)=2^{-kb}(s^{kb}+t^{kb})\pmod M$$

Supposing that $(1)$ holds for $i$ gives
$$\begin{align}S_{i+1}&=P_b(S_i)
\\\\&\equiv P_b(2^{-kb^{i+1}}(s^{kb^{i+1}}+t^{kb^{i+1}}))\pmod M
\\\\&=2^{-b}\cdot\bigg(\bigg(2^{-kb^{i+1}}(s^{kb^{i+1}}+t^{kb^{i+1}})-\sqrt{(2^{-kb^{i+1}}(s^{kb^{i+1}}+t^{kb^{i+1}}))^2-4}\bigg)^b
\\&\qquad\qquad+\bigg(2^{-kb^{i+1}}(s^{kb^{i+1}}+t^{kb^{i+1}})+\sqrt{(2^{-kb^{i+1}}(s^{kb^{i+1}}+t^{kb^{i+1}}))^2-4}\bigg)^b\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-b}\cdot\bigg(\bigg(2^{-kb^{i+1}}(s^{kb^{i+1}}+t^{kb^{i+1}})-\sqrt{(2^{-kb^{i+1}}(t^{kb^{i+1}}-s^{kb^{i+1}}))^2}\bigg)^b
\\&\qquad\qquad +\bigg(2^{-kb^{i+1}}(s^{kb^{i+1}}+t^{kb^{i+1}})+\sqrt{(2^{-kb^{i+1}}(t^{kb^{i+1}}-s^{kb^{i+1}}))^2}\bigg)^b\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-b}\cdot\bigg(\bigg(2^{-kb^{i+1}}(s^{kb^{i+1}}+t^{kb^{i+1}})-2^{-kb^{i+1}}(t^{kb^{i+1}}-s^{kb^{i+1}})\bigg)^b
\\&\qquad\qquad+\bigg(2^{-kb^{i+1}}(s^{kb^{i+1}}+t^{kb^{i+1}})+2^{-kb^{i+1}}(t^{kb^{i+1}}-s^{kb^{i+1}})\bigg)^b\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-kb^{i+2}}(s^{kb^{i+2}}+t^{kb^{i+2}})\qquad\square\end{align}$$

From $(1)$, we get, using $2(a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4})=(\sqrt{a+2}\pm\sqrt{a-2})^2$,
$$\begin{align}S_{n-1}&\equiv 2^{-(M+c)}(s^{M+c}+t^{M+c})\pmod M
\\\\&=2^{-2M-2c}\bigg((\sqrt{a+2}-\sqrt{a-2})^{2M+2c}
\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad +(\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{a-2})^{2M+2c}\bigg)\tag2\end{align}$$

Here, we have, by the binomial theorem,
$$\begin{align}&(\sqrt{a+2}\pm\sqrt{a-2})^{M}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{M}\binom Mk(\sqrt{a+2})^{M-k}(\pm\sqrt{a-2})^k
\\\\&=\sqrt{a+2}\sum_{j=0}^{(M-1)/2}\binom{M}{2j}(a+2)^{(M-2j-1)/2}(a-2)^{j}
\\&\qquad\qquad \pm\sqrt{a-2}\sum_{j=1}^{(M+1)/2}\binom{M}{2j-1}(a+2)^{(M-2j+1)/2}(a-2)^{j-1}\end{align}$$

So, there are integers $C,D$ such that
$$(\sqrt{a+2}\pm\sqrt{a-2})^{M}=C\sqrt{a+2}\pm D\sqrt{a-2}$$
where
$$C=\sum_{j=0}^{(M-1)/2}\binom{M}{2j}(a+2)^{(M-2j-1)/2}(a-2)^{j}\equiv \left(\frac{a+2}{M}\right)\equiv 1\pmod M$$
and
$$D=\sum_{j=1}^{(M+1)/2}\binom{M}{2j-1}(a+2)^{(M-2j+1)/2}(a-2)^{j-1}\equiv \left(\frac{a-2}{M}\right)\equiv -1\pmod M$$

From $(2)$, we get
$$\begin{align}2^{2(M-1)}\cdot S_{n-1}&\equiv 2^{-2c-2}\left((\sqrt{a+2}-\sqrt{a-2})^{2M+2c}+(\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{a-2})^{2M+2c}\right)\pmod M
\\\\&=2^{-2c-2}\bigg((\sqrt{a+2}-\sqrt{a-2})^{2c}(C\sqrt{a+2}- D\sqrt{a-2})^2
\\&\qquad +(\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{a-2})^{2c}(C\sqrt{a+2}+ D\sqrt{a-2})^2\bigg)
\\\\&\equiv 2^{-2c-2}\bigg((\sqrt{a+2}-\sqrt{a-2})^{2c}(\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{a-2})^2
\\&\qquad +(\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{a-2})^{2c}(\sqrt{a+2}-\sqrt{a-2})^2\bigg)\pmod M
\\\\&=2^{-2c+2}\bigg((\sqrt{a+2}-\sqrt{a-2})^{2c-2}+(\sqrt{a+2}+\sqrt{a-2})^{2c-2}\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-(c-1)}(s^{c-1}+t^{c-1})
\\\\&=P_{c-1}(a)\end{align}$$
It follows from $2^{2(M-1)}\equiv 1\pmod M$ that 
$$S_{n-1}\equiv P_{c-1}(a)\pmod M$$

---

*Proof for Claim 2* :

From $(1)$, we get, similarly as above,
$$\begin{align}2^{2(N-1)}\cdot S_{n-1}&\equiv 2^{N+c-2}(s^{N-c}+t^{N-c})\pmod N
\\\\&=2^{2c-2}((\sqrt{s+2}-\sqrt{s-2})^{2N-2c}+(\sqrt{s+2}+\sqrt{s-2})^{2N-2c})
\\\\&=2^{2c-2}\bigg((\sqrt{s+2}-\sqrt{s-2})^{2N}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{s+2}+\sqrt{s-2}}{4}\bigg)^{2c}
\\&\qquad\qquad +(\sqrt{s+2}+\sqrt{s-2})^{2N}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{s+2}-\sqrt{s-2}}{4}\bigg)^{2c}\bigg)
\\\\&\equiv 2^{-2c-2}((\sqrt{s+2}-\sqrt{s-2})^2(\sqrt{s+2}+\sqrt{s-2})^{2c}
\\&\qquad\qquad +(\sqrt{s+2}+\sqrt{s-2})^2(\sqrt{s+2}-\sqrt{s-2})^{2c})\pmod N
\\\\&=2^{-2c+2}((\sqrt{s+2}+\sqrt{s-2})^{2c-2}+(\sqrt{s+2}-\sqrt{s-2})^{2c-2})
\\\\&=2^{-(c-1)}(s^{c-1}+t^{c-1})
\\\\&=P_{c-1}(a)\end{align}$$
It follows from $2^{2(N-1)}\equiv 1\pmod N$ that 
$$S_{n-1}\equiv P_{c-1}(a)\pmod N$$